# WMI APIs hang when supplied incorrect credentials

Tags: c#, wmi

I've found multiple online tutorials for establishing WMI connections to remote machines using c#.  These tutorials describe a process like the following:

```
ConnectionOptions cOpts = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementObjectCollection moCollection;
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher;
ManagementScope mScope;
ObjectQuery oQuery;

mScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\{1}", host.hostname, "ROOT\\CIMV2"), cOpts);
oQuery = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, oQuery);

moCollection = moSearcher.Get();
```

The happy path cases - connecting to a local host, or connecting to a remote host with proper credentials - work fine.  I'm working on a project where we need to support the case when the currently logged in account does not have access to the remote host we're attempting to connect to.  That is, we need to catch this case, bring the bad credentials to the attention of the user, and prompt them to supply credentials again.

When I specify credentials in my ConnectionOptions object that do not have context on the remote machine, my call to moSearcher.Get() hangs (seemingly) indefinitely.  Similarly, a call to the Connect() function in ManagementScope hangs in the same manner.

We have similar logic in place to perform the equivalent WMI commands in c++, and I can report that those return almost immediately if improper credentials are supplied.  An appropriate "access is denied" message is returned.  The hosts I'm using for test purposes right now are the same ones we use when testing our existing c++ logic, so I have no reason to believe that WMI is incorrectly configured in our environment.

I've searched for timeout issues surrounding WMI connections in c#.  I've explored the Timeout property of ConnectionOptions and moSearcher.Options.  I've also looked at the ReturnImmediately property of the EnumerationOptions object that can be associated with ManagementObjectSearcher instance.  These options did not have the desired effect for me.

I suppose I could perform these WMI commands in a separate thread, and surround the thread with monitoring code that kills it if it hasn't returned in a reasonable amount of time.  That seems like a fair amount of work that would be pushed to all consumers of the c# WMI routines, and I'm hoping there's an easier way.  Plus, I'm not sure that killing an outstanding thread this way properly cleans up the WMI connection.

Pinging the remote host doesn't do me any good, because knowing the host is up and running does not tell me if the credentials I have are appropriate (and if the c# WMI calls will hang).  Is there another way to validate the credentials against a remote host?

It's always possible that there's an obvious flag or API I'm missing, because I would think others have run into this problem.  Any information/assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks for reading this lengthy post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all your special functions are, but here's a little routine to help you troubleshoot that should be able to wrap your routine in a thread and give it 5 seconds to execute:

```
void Fake() {
  bool ok = false;
  ConnectionOptions cOpts = new ConnectionOptions();
  ManagementObjectCollection moCollection;
  ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher;
  ManagementScope mScope;
  ObjectQuery oQuery;
  if (cOpts != null) {
    mScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\{1}", host.hostname, "ROOT\\CIMV2"), cOpts);
    if (mScope != null) {
      oQuery = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
      if (oQuery != null) {
        moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, oQuery);
        if (moSearcher != null) {
          ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
          Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => {
            moCollection = moSearcher.Get();
            mre.Set();
          };
          thread1.Start();
          ok = mre.WaitOne(5000); // wait 5 seconds
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine("ManagementObjectSearcher failed");
        }
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("ObjectQuery failed");
      }
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("ManagementScope failed");
    }
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("ConnectionOptions failed");
  }
}
```

Hope that helps or gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks jp for the quick response.  That separate thread code is an option.  What might make me feel better is to find that other people experience the same issue when exercising these APIs in the manner I am.

Comment: Note also that the error checking all along the way to notify you, the developer, that something has gone amiss. If your code makes it all the way through the error checking steps to the line `moCollection = moSearcher.Get()`, then you may want to look up the `Get()` function to see if it has any overloads or error codes it provides. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: For example, this link >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67a77ef1.aspx << says, "`Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by partially trusted code.`"

Comment: Error checking does not save me in this case.  That is, none of the objects are null following their constructors.  Looks like I'll have to go the separate thread route.  Hopefully others that run into this problem can benefit from this post and save time.  Thanks for the input jp.

Answer (score 0):

I took jp's suggestion to surround the WMI API calls in a separate thread that could be killed if they exceeded a timeout.  When testing, the separate thread threw an exception of type System.UnauthorizedAccessException.  I removed the threading logic and added a catch statement to handle this exception type.  Sure enough, the exception is caught almost immediately following the call to ManagementObjectSearcher.Get().

```
try
{
    moCollection = moSearcher.Get();
}

catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    return Program.ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED;
}

catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error, caught COMException.");
    return Program.ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED;
}
```

(Note that the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException catch statement already existed in my code)

I don't know why this exception isn't thrown (or at least is not brought to the user's attention through the VS 2010 IDE) when executed as part of the parent thread.  In any event, this is exactly what I was looking for, and is consistent with the behavior of the WMI connection routines in c++.